# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui' -> in all IDEs no matter what I try

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've been trying to look for a solution online for hours with no avail.

**I have this piece of code:**

```
#load packages
import pyautogui    #these are for our clicks and keystrokes!
import time         #required to call any time commands (i.e delay)

#STEP ONE --> Get Cursor Location
time.sleep(2)
prin

t(pyautogui.position())
```

**But everytime I try to run this script I get the following error:**

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 "/home/silo/Documents/Python Projects/macro 1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/silo/Documents/Python Projects/macro 1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui    #these are for our clicks and keystrokes!
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is what happens when I try to install **any** package in settings:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0145.png)

**I am currently using:**

1. Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera
2. Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
3. Python 3.9.5
4. Pip 9.0.1 (I have already upgraded pip to latest version via terminal, though I think this is still for Python 3.6)

**I've tried (but to no success):**

- Installing pyautogui, pillow, plotly, matplotlib
- Changing pyCharm's Python interpreter to /usr/bin/python3.9 (strangely, pyCharm names this path Python 3.6)
- Removed all instances of Python 2.7
- `alias = 'Python 3.9'`
- `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/dir"`
- Installed everything with: `$ python3 -m pip <...>`

Comment: Have you tried executing your code with the same python interpreter (command line python3) that you have used to install dependencies?

Comment: have you check your IDE python interpreter and Terminal interpreter are same or not?

Comment: yes I have tried both comments, still no luck and the interpreters do represent each other